# Can't query certain namespaces/classes in WMI (Get-WmiObject: Not supported)

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

I'm trying to query classes in the `root\microsoft\windows\managementtools` namespace, but am getting an odd error. I have confirmed this namespace exists on my machine, because I can query it using WMIExplorer. Here is the error:

```
C:\> Get-WmiObject -Namespace ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\ManagementTools -Query "SELECT * FROM MSFT_MTRegistryKey"
Get-WmiObject : Not supported
At line:1 chat:1 ...
```

I am running this local to the Windows 2016 server and through an Administrator powershell. I confirmed the Administrator group has all accesses in the WMI security tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the `GetKey` method of that class [returns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/mtregprov/msft-mtregistrykey-getkey) an object of the same class, I don't think you can query it in this way. What you are effectively doing is getting an instance of every single key in the entire registry of the local computer. [This site](http://metadataconsulting.blogspot.com/2016/07/windows-10-registry-size-number-of-keys-number-of-key-value-pairs.html) claims that number would be in the millions.

Perhaps you want to try

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Namespace root\microsoft\windows\managementtools -Class MSFT_MTRegistryKey -Name GetKey -ArgumentList '<name of key>'
```

On the return object you can then call `GetSubKeys` or `GetValues` on its `Result` property.

Incidentally, there is also the [StdRegProv](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/regprov/stdregprov) class for querying the registry with WMI/CIM.